# jQuery - Block input until after $.getJson is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, synchronize

I need to make sure that all user-input is blocked until the json data are recieved and processed. I read somewhere that I can do this with Deffered objects, but it doesn't seem to work.
My code:

```js
function checkDTCCardAvailability() {
    var defer = $.Deferred(),
    isAvailable = defer.then(function() {
        $('#pass-search-form').block({
            message: '<h4>Please Wait</h4>',
            css: {
                backgroundColor: '#0192af',
                color: '#f6d200'
            }
        });

        $.getJSON("site_url",{
            city: 'Athens',
            age: 25
        }, function(j) {
            //process data         
            alert(j);
        }); //JSON call
    });

    defer.resolve();
    isAvailable.done(function() {
        // Enable form  
        $('#pass-search-form').unblock();
    });
}
```

Sometimes the screen will unblock before the alert shows up. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think it will solve any problem, but why using PHP to echo a simple string ? `message: '<h4>Please Wait</h4>'` would do the same

Comment: move the unblock to where you now have alert(j)

Comment: @TouPye, no reason. I had some other code there that needed php and I forgot to edit it out when I posted the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put the `unblock()` in your `getJSON` callback it will wait until the response:

```
$.getJSON("site_url", {
    city: 'Athens',
    age: 25
}, function (j) {
    //process data          
    alert(j);

    // Enable form      
    $('#pass-search-form').unblock();
}); //JSON call
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what you want, but you can do that :

```
$.getJSON("site_url", {
   city: 'Athens',
   age: 25
})
   .done(function( jsonResp ){
      // Success callback
   })
   .fail(function(){
      // Server error callback
   })
   .always(function(){
      // in all cases
      $('#pass-search-form').unblock();
   });
```